# python random does not behave as expected in loop

Tags: python

I have 2 examples of python random giving different results although logically they should be the same

```
    In [8]: random.seed(100)

In [9]: for i in range(2):
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...:     a = [1,2,3,45]
   ...:     random.shuffle(a)
   ...:     random.randint(10,20)
   ...:     print a
   ...:     random.seed(100)
   ...:     
[1, 45, 3, 2]
[45, 3, 2, 1]


In [6]: for i in range(2):
   ...:     random.seed(100)
   ...:    
   ...:     a = [1,2,3,45]
   ...:     random.shuffle(a)
   ...:     random.randint(10,20)
   ...:     print a
   ...:     random.seed(100)
   ...:     
   ...:     
[45, 3, 2, 1]
[45, 3, 2, 1]
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Have you run this multiple times? Are you sure your random.shuffle() didnt shuffle this into the exact same order?

Comment: yes. i have used ipython so it shows the sequence of command run

Comment: on second loop the random sequence it uses for shuffling is the same for each and every iteration.

Comment: @blacksite that wouldn't be an issue, that'll just move the random counter down 10 times. I used something similar in a program to help make an option more random was that I timed how long it took the user to hit the button, then did `random.randint(0,num_of_milliseconds)`  to change it. The randint never got set to anything, it just ran the random counter so that different values were generated.

Comment: @Aceminer with your new edit I can't reproduce your results, they are coming out the same. Try running it here: (https://repl.it/repls/AjarDarkslateblueFrog)

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeding the random number generator in your first example *before* calling shuffle() for the first time, so you will get a (pseudo) random result.

In the lower example, you always seed the random number generator before calling shuffle(), so you will always get the same result.

Comment: I edited my example to illustrate my point better. i missed it out

Comment: Let me try it on another pc or something. I am sure I didn’t do anything funky